# Authenticating Access against another website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, iis-7.5, security

I have a number of sites that I have been asked to authenticate against the login of another site.

Would anyone have any idea how to achieve this or have experience solving such a problem.

My initial thought was a web service. But how to implement this is my question? I may have multiple websites built with multiple programming languages in multiple locations.

Initially I will be working with asp.net sites exclusively so any advice on how to add a global web service security check would be appreciated! I can edit the code in these instances but I was hoping I could keep this minimal. Possibly just a few lines to a global file or on application start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to Federated Authentication, where an application (the Relying Party) permits a trusted authentication service (the Identity Provider) to authenticate users on its behalf.

Read up on [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351); it's the easiest place to start with federated authentication, particularly with MVC.

WIF can be used to integrate your application with an Identity Provider (such as Windows Live ID) with just a small amount of configuration. You can also build your own, custom Identity Provider if you wish.

Don't try to reinvent the wheel by doing this yourself. There are established standards for implementing Federated Authentication.